# Kubectl apply command for updating existing service resource

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build

Currently I'm using Kubernetes version 1.11.+. Previously I'm always using the following command for my *cloud build* scripts:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
  id: 'deploy'
  args:
  - 'apply'
  - '-f'
  - 'k8s'
  - '--recursive'
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=${_REGION}'
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=${_CLUSTER_NAME}'
```

And the commands just working as expected, at that time I'm using k8s version 1.10.+. However recently I got the following error:

> - spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable
> - metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: "": must be specified for an update

So I'm wondering if this is an expected behavior for Service resources?

Here's my YAML config for my service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {name}
  namespace: {namespace}
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "{backend-config-name}"}'
spec:
  ports:
   - port: {port-num}
     targetPort: {port-num}
  selector:
    app: {label}
    environment: {env}
type: NodePort
```

Comment: What does your YAML look like?

Comment: Hi I already included my YAML configuration, thanks..

Comment: Is that the only YAML service in your k8s directory?

Comment: No, it's including deployment and ingress as well. However, the only file that causing this problem is service configuration. That's why I only give you the service configuration.

Comment: I have found helpful the article - https://www.timcosta.io/kubernetes-service-invalid-clusterip-or-resourceversion/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71042

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/66602 should be picked to 1.11

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes meet this error when manually running `kubectl apply -f somefile.yaml`.
I think it happens when someone have changed the specification through the Kubernetes Dashboard instead of by applying new changes through `kubectl apply`.

To fix it, I run `kubectl edit services/servicename` which opens the yaml specification in my default editor. Then remove the fields `metadata.resourceVersion` and `spec.clusterIP`, hit save and run `kubectl apply -f somefile.yaml` again.

Comment: Removing the fields, it came back with an error
`# services "servicename" was not valid:
# * metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: "": must be specified for an update
# * metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: "": must be specified for an update
# * spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the spec.clusterIP on your service yaml file with value to be replaced with clusterIP address from service as shown below:

```
spec:
  clusterIP:
```

Your issue is discuused on the following [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25241) there as well a workaround to help you bypass this issue.

Comment: won't it by any chance will causing an outage?